# LinkedIn-j get Company Updates

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

In java `Linkedin-j` is it possible to get the company post and updates? I analyzed the API It have search functionality only. Is any body know how to get the posts of a particular company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method to get the company updates in linkedin-j. They did not update in this API.
You would try to use    `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?event-type=status-update` through your code

Refer [this](http://sundarishree.blogspot.in/2011/05/simple-java-program-using-linkedin-api.html) for how to send request to Linked In and get results